# What changes are required to use Hibernate along with IBatis and jdbc connection pooling

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

We want to integrate Hibernate 5 in our project, and complexity is that we are using IBatis with Spring 4 
my persistence.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/MYJNDI" />

    <!-- SqlMap setup for iBATIS Database Layer -->
    <bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/sql-map-mysql.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

    <!-- Generic Dao - can be used when doing standard CRUD -->
    <bean id="baseDaoiBATIS" class="com.test.database.BaseDaoiBATIS">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:mybatis-resources/*.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.test.database.mapper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName" value="${redis.hostname}"></property>
        <property name="port" value="${redis.port}"></property>
        <property name="usePool" value="true"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="stringRedisSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"></bean>

    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory"></property>
        <property name="keySerializer" ref="stringRedisSerializer"></property>
        <property name="hashKeySerializer" ref="stringRedisSerializer"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

What changes we should do to have Hibernate5 along with IBatis Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated 
Note: We are using spring4,Ibatis ,Connection pooling

Comment: Configure hibernate, use the same datasource, change the transactionmanager to the hibernate one and that is more or less all you need.

Comment: I changed <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>  TO 

  <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>    After this my application is not coming up

Comment: I tried this also <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.test.database</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties"><props>..</props>
        </property> </bean>

Comment: @M.Deinum can you give a minimal config so that I can start with.

Comment: Obviously using `hibernate3` classes will not work you have to use those from the `hibernate5` package.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I find out that we are using spring 3.0.2.RELEASE orm for ibatis because in Spring4 Ibatis support is not available.Any suggestion that which Hibernate version i should use which will work with Spring 3.0.2.RELEASE orm?

Comment: Please don't... Never mix jars of different versions of a framework (currently you are apparently mixing Spring 4 and Spring 3 classes) that is going to lead to issues. Ibatis isn't supported anymore because the project is dead. YOu should use MyBatis as a replacement. I believe Spring 3 supports only hibernate 3 (maybe 4) but definitly not 5. In your case I would strongly suggest to ditch the Spring 3 dependency (it will lead to issues) but move to MyBatis and then introduce Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made changes as per suggestion by @M.Deinum and it's working:
Approach we followed are:
[1] using Hibernate-3 with spring 3
[2] using Hibernate Transaction Manager instead of DataSourceTransactionManager :

```
<!-- <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.database.domain" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>  
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
   </bean> 
   <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```